# How to reconcile git no longer recognizing existing gitconfig files on commits?

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-config

I've had my config set up on my ubuntu 21.04 and now 22.10 PopOS linux laptop for months and was able to use git on the command line and in vscode no problem. Since this morning, when i try to commit it fails with "Configuration could not be found."
The git error log:

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
Configuration could not be found.
```

yet when I check git config --global user keys, I get back the config. I tried deleting and creating a new config, and adding user keys to the local git/config but the same issue.
The only thing that has changed is system updates and latest stable VSCode, but the git issues exist on the command line outside of it. Does anyone know how I can reconcile this?

Comment: The string `configuration could not be found` occurs nowhere in Git (in any capitalization); `could not be found` occurs in a few comments and in two irrelevant Perl modules (for working with SVN). So this is not coming from standard Git.

Comment: do you have any custom hooks installed ?

Comment: I had the same issue. In `.git/hooks` directory there was a file `pre_commit` with `npx lint-staged` command, not sure where it came from (maybe from running `npx browserslist@latest --update-db`, just a guess) but after removing the `pre_commit` file I can commit again.